# How to filter for columns where the first row (not header) starts with string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to filter a dataframe by the first row, but can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Here's a sample version of the data I'm working with:

```py
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame(
    ...:     [['Open-Ended Response', 'Open-Ended Response', 'Response', 'Response'], [1, 2, 3, 4]],
    ...:     columns=list('ABCD'),
    ...: )

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
                     A                    B         C         D
0  Open-Ended Response  Open-Ended Response  Response  Response
1                    1                    2         3         4
```

What I want to do is filter for all columns that start with "Response" in the first non-header row. So in this case, just have the last two columns in there own dataframe.

I can easily filter the header with something like this:

```
respo = [col for col in df if col.startswith('Response')]
```

But it doesn't seem to work if it's the 1t non-header row. Importantly, I need to keep the current header after I filter.

Thank you.

Comment: The code should work I think. there are two rows in your image,  'Response' is in your 2nd row? Print your column names using ```df.columns.tolist()``` and view them, perhaps it will show why your code does not work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For best results, please read the guide on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, don't post images of code or data - please include a snippet which would allow us to work with the same example. That helps us get started quickly and minimizes misinterpretation. If possible, try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Happy asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to select the *values* of the first row:

```py
df.iloc[0]  # selects the values in the first row
```

Then, use python's `.str` StringAccessor methods for working with *data values* rather than column names:

```py
df.iloc[0].str.startswith('Response') # Test the result of the above line
```

This will give you a Series with True/False values indexed by column name. Finally, use this to select the *columns* from your dataframe based on the matched labels:

```py
df.loc[:, df.iloc[0].str.startswith('Response')] # Select columns based on the test
```

This should do the trick!

See pandas's docs on [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) and the [StringAccessor methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern) for more help.